# What happened to the Magento wiki?

Tags: discussion, documentation

It looks like wiki was removed and replaced with various documentation pages.

There used to be pages such as:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150411014432/http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

These would be a handy reference to use in answering questions on SO since they were pretty decently written and there wasn't really anywhere else that documented a lot of this stuff.

Now, when looking for those pages, it seems they simply don't exist anymore rather than being moved somewhere else.

**What happened to these pages and what would be a good replacement for adding reference links in SO answers?**

Comment: Why is this on Magento meta? Shouldn't this be on the main site? And do you have a date when you first saw that the content has been removed? And perhaps a date when you last looked and it still was there?

Answer (score 2):

We're working on some replacement content, but there will not be a 1:1 replacement. In the future the Magento 2 docs will be a good replacement.

Comment: request to you,kindly put  magnto 1 doc in where.. Developer guys  facing lot of for not getting data of magent 1

Comment: I think that having thousands links to this or that magento wiki pages and just drop them all is not good at all. Maybe there should be some old.community.magento.com place to access all that content while you replacing content?

Comment: Hey ben, I am looking forward to the magento 2 docs going up. But we're now missing a lot of good docs that were used to help train people in Magento 1! I agree with @AmitBera, having the v1 visible somewhere would be great.

Comment: I would like add to AmitBera and Sharif's comments that not only are a lot of internal links broken, traffic from Google is also suffering. There are a lot of knowledge base and forum pages in the SERPS, which are now all redirecting to the developer portal. The content on those pages might have been a bit stale, but removing all this information collected over the years seems pretty extreme.

Comment: I'm being a bit paranoid maybe, but this seems like it's been done on purpose to encourage developers to move to Magento 2.. There was absolutely no need to remove the old documentation instead of just adding the new one.

Answer (score 2):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-1.html